# Page is not redirecting by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a dynamic website and from .htaccess file creating clean URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+\ ]+)$ flight.php?flights=$1&slug=$1
```

This code worked fine for me but when I created a new type of page and trying to get clean URLs with the same code i.e.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+\ ]+)$ manual-page.php?url=$1&slug=$1
```

This is not working and if I comment the previous two lines then its is working fine.

Only one code is working at a time.

For first I have a URL domain.com/flight.php?flight-san-fransisco-london-flights and I want this being redirect to domain.com/san-fransisco-london-flights & from the second one I have domain.com/manual-page.php?url=my-new-page and I want this being redirect todomain.com/my-new-page.

Is these any way to get both working together?

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for certain conditions - or a way for Apache to detect you want rule 2 vs rule 1. Perhaps some prefixed keyword?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.png|.jpg|.gif|.jpeg|.bmp)$
RewriteRule ^flights-([a-zA-Z0-9_-+\ ]+)$ flight.php?flights=$1&slug=$1
RewriteRule ^manual-([a-zA-Z0-9_-+\ ]+)$ manual-page.php?url=$1&slug=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific for your rules. Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteRule ^.*\.php?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+\ ]+)$ $1
```